# logical shift left losing bits after sign extend in assembly ARMv8

Tags: assembly, armv8

I am using sign extend to change a 32-bit variable into a 64-bit variable. However, when I use logical shift left on the 64-bit variable it loses bits as though it is still 32-bit.

I want to be able to eventually shift everything from my original variable to the upper side of the 64-bit variable. (0xFFFFFFFF00000000 is the result I am expecting)

The code below shows a shift of 8 bits to demonstrate where the bits are lost:

```
str_fmt:.string "\nWord Value: 0x%08x \nWord Extended to 64-bit: 0x%016x\nLSL: 0x%016x\n\n"

        .balign 4   
        .global main    

main:   stp     x29, x30, [sp, -16]!    
        mov     x29, sp         

        mov     w19, 0xFFFFFFFF
        sxtw    x20, w19

        lsl     x21, x20, 8

results:
        adrp    x0, str_fmt     
        add     x0, x0, :lo12:str_fmt
        mov     w1, w19             
        mov     x2, x20
        mov     x3, x21
        bl      printf

done:   ldp     x29, x30, [sp], 16  
        ret
```

The output is as follows:

Word Value: 0xffffffff
Word Extended to 64-bit: 0x00000000ffffffff
LSL: 0x00000000ffffff00

What am I missing in my code to allow the logical shift left to result in 0xFFFFFFFF00000000?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `x` formatting specifier prints an `unsigned` argument which is a 32 bit type on the ARM ABIs I know. This causes `printf` to ignore the high 32 bits of the argument. Use `llx` to print a `long long unsigned` argument; `long long unsigned` is at least a 64 bit type.

Comment: Tried your solution, it changes the printing format but does not solve the problem of logical shift left losing bits

Comment: @Sarchwalk You are sure you've fixed both instances?

Comment: I get an incessant amount of zeros followed by ffffffff and ffffff00 in the last case @fuz

Comment: got it working, was using a 1 and not an l. Thanks for your help!